# Travis CI is not case-sensitive by default?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpunit, filesystems, travis-ci

I have a php project that has composer dependencies which are inherently tested in the code path of my unit tests. Here's my sample code:

```
<?php
// where FooBar is a composer package but I'm purposely typing it incorrectly here
use \fooBaR
public function appendNameToWords(array $words, $name)
{
    $start = microtime(true);
    $newWords = array_map(function($word){
      return $word . $name;
    }, $words);
    // logs the diff between start and end time
    FooBar::logTimer($start);
    return $newWords;
}
```

My test is simply testing the method but of course executes the line `FooBar::logTimer` in my source code. The problem is I'm expecting my test to fail if I mistype the class `FooBar` to be `fooBaR`. Unfortunately, the travis build is passing...but i'm unclear why.

`.travis.yml` file:

```
 language: php
 php:
 - 5.6
 install:        script/install
 script:
 - script/test
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not case sensitive when it comes to class names. If your code declares a class named `Foo`, and this definition is executed, you can also instantiate any other case style, like `foo` or `fOO`.

PHP will preserve the case of the occurrence that triggers the autoload (i.e. the first time PHP encounters a class name), and if that case style does not match a case sensitive file name, using the class will fail.

I consider writing the class in the correct case style a problem that **should not be tested** with a unit test. It's a problem that cannot be solved in your own code - and it is basically not existing if you use a powerful IDE that knows all classes that can be used.

Additionally: Your question does not provide code that demonstrates the problem. And it contains code that probably does not do what you think it does.